# Using html as input for a knockout-component

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am in the process of implementing some components in my codebase. However, I have ran into an smaller issue with the template part. I would like to send in the template as an input to a knockout-component but I am not sure how to do it or if it even is possible.

Taking an example from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html I hope that I can do something like this:

```
<like-or-dislike params="value: userRating">

    <div class="like-or-dislike" data-bind="visible: !chosenValue()">
        <button data-bind="click: like">Like it</button>
        <button data-bind="click: dislike">Dislike it</button>
     </div>

    <div class="result" data-bind="visible: chosenValue">
        You <strong data-bind="text: chosenValue"></strong> it.
        And this was loaded from an external file.
    </div>

</like-or-dislike>
```

But I cannot find any documentation if that works at all. The reason why I want to implement it that way is simply because I am having some server generated html that I want to still be a part of a component. Otherwise I will have to make it a json-object and render the html inside the component which seems like a unnecessary extra step. The good thing about using components is that the logic is seperated in it's own file and it is easier to seperate logic between different components. I understand that if I do it like this I have to copy the html if I want to reuse the component.

Am I thinking of this the wrong way or is this possible?

Thanks for your sage advice and better wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I fully understand your situation but I think I may have the answer. You can actually have the server generate `<script type="text/html">` and use that (by id of course) with a component. The KO documentation is pretty poor on component templating, but here is an example using an element.

A couple of things I've learned with components. The viewmodel must be declared before declaration, and the `<script>` must be in the dom prior to binding.

```js
function ComponentViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Title = ko.observable("This is a Component VM");
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.ExampleComponent = ko.observable({
    name: 'Example'
  });

}


ko.components.register('Example', {
  template: {
    element: 'ComponentTemplate'
  },
  viewModel: ComponentViewModel
})



ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<script id="ComponentTemplate" type="text/html">
  <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
</script>

<div data-bind="component: ExampleComponent"> </div>
```

I won't devalue components, but I also would point you to using templates with a data binding, it's essentially the same thing (please correct me if I'm wrong). and doesn't require the component be established. This is better for situations where the would-be component occurs less frequently.

```js
function ComponentViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Title = ko.observable("This is a Template with a VM");
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.ComponentVM = ko.observable(new ComponentViewModel());

  self.ExampleComponent = ko.observable({
    name: 'ExampleTemplate', // This is the ID
    data: self.ComponentVM
  });

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script id="ExampleTemplate" type="text/html">
  <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: ExampleComponent"> </div>
```

I hope these help!